# cordova plugin network interface issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2

Downloaded the plugin from https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface

Can't use any global variable or call any other function inside the function

```
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { alert(ip);});
```

If I use something like this

```
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) 
{ alert(ip);
this.test(ip); });

test(x){
console.log("IP = "+ x);}
```

I get an error:

> **Error in Success callbackId: networkinterface1280836273 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of null.**

I get the Ip alert properly but I can't access it outside the provided function.
Also typerscript gives the error:

> **[ts] Cannot find name 'networkinterface'.**

When I use the plugin. But it still compiles and works.

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: I guess the this-pointer is not what you think it is... Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921266/saving-the-application-state-on-cordovas-pause-with-angular). I think your doing the same mistake as I did.

Comment: The errors seem to be saying that the plugin is not *fully* present, even though it still works (strange). I've had similar issues where the cause was the plugin not having been added. I would try adding the plugin manually to the project to be sure (not sure how to do this using ionic).

Comment: thanks @Phonolog for the help

Comment: @ThomCunningham no the plugin is correctly installed. Apparently I need to do something with the typings file. Need to add some reference to it. Still trying to figure out how to remove [ts]connot find name 'networkinterface'.
although the plugins works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved..(thanks to the ionic community) need to use to the lambda function `=>` to capture the meaning of this from the surrounding context. More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#lambdas-and-using-this)

```
loadIPAddress() {
    networkinterface.getIPAddress((ip) => {
      alert(ip);
      this.test(ip);
    });
  }

  test(x) {
    console.log("IP = "+ x);
  }
```